# Angular filter that generates html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small angular filter that insert an (bootstrap) icon in place of a true value.
It works but the html is encoded:

```
  var conApp = angular.module('conApp', []);
  conApp.filter('trueIcon', function($filter){
    return function(booleanValue){
        return booleanValue ? '<i class="icon-ok"></i>' : '';
    }
  });
```

Do i have to implement another filter to decode the html ?
Is there an "angular" way of doing this ?

Answer (score 28):

You need to use ng-bind-html to render html.

```
<span ng-bind-html="foo | trueIcon"></span>
```

That said... that's really not what filters are for. Filters are more for scrubbing data being written to a view, rather than generating elements of the view/DOM itself. You'll probably be better off creating a directive for that:

```
app.directive('trueIcon', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<i ng-class="{\'icon-ok\': value, \'icon-not-okay\': !value}"></i>',
      scope: {
         value: '='
      }
   };
});

<true-icon value="foo"></true-icon>
```

Comment: @blesh In this case +1 for you as well :-) You are also answering massive amount of questions!

Comment: Any reason why i can't define my directive as 'true-icon' ? Are directive names always camelcased ?

Comment: Angular just expects them to be camelcase. IIRC, they don't work if you declare them with the dashes.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I'm "scrubbing" \r\n and replacing it with <br/> so hopefully not violating the intended use of filters too much.

Comment: Why do you say this isn't what filters are for?  In the Angular tutorial, the [first example of custom filters](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/docs/tutorial/step_09) does the same thing but with UTF characters instead of html markup.

Comment: @colllin: That example was adding unicode characters to a *string*. What the OP is trying to do here is generate/manipulate HTML and apply it to the DOM, which is what directives are for.

Answer (score 6):

AngularJS is sanitizing results of expression evaluation by default. To display HTML as markup you've got 2 options:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml (from the ngSanitize module)
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe (I wouldn't recommend this one as it opens up potential security risks).

While the above will make your filter work, maybe you should consider turning it into a directive?

Comment: +1 to you because we both said basically the same thing... and I see you around all the time.

Comment: I think your links are no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I found for the case of converting \r\n to 
 is to use a small function and *ngFor.

In your ts file, add the function

```
splitLines(text: String): string[] {
  return text.split(/\r?\n/);
}
```

In html

```
<span *ngFor="let row of splitLines(multilineStringVariable)">
  {{row}}<br/>
</span>
```